# Google Oaut2 - Python using requests whiout Library

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I am trying to authenticate not google by means of requests if I use the api but I don't know what I put in the "code" field and it will work, you can help me, or the code follows below.

```
import requests

url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

payload='grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=xxxxx&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpushsistemas.com.br%2F&code='
headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Cookie': 'NID=219=RgUebbUM4k3WX0uQr8HVcIZkQ5-rMrb4HHnfnRzNTxUse776sG6-LItgXwpdv-MmaFYf3Tu4otJN-UfP70OzDtdnfam2dwAZkd6yMsr8BW_7lGE4FTaas9QkoG-hOMqXgYEHvI4YK39dWgXhWnL0E5LcsOv0DXnfjJ2kUf7VlTs; __Host-GAPS=1:jGXTa0ipDEC58oJF7pZwNBVeSXCQRw:3IRHy3GC9mAq4nqt'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

This output

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code"
}
```

if it is not possible to do this way could you send me how to do it using the google library?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization#generating_a_refresh_token).
You will first have to generate the code, see step 3.

Comment: I understand, thank you would be able to help me get this code, just do a get in the url?

Comment: @Lyux My goal is to get the token for dialogflow

Comment: You might want to try the given steps. Step 1 has to be done **manually**.

Comment: @Lyux I managed to generate the token using the tutorial, but the token went to the play store did not work in dialogflow, which url should I put in place of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher for step 1, plus one thank you time.